# Constructor for empty grouped data frame/tibble in dplyr

Tags: r, constructor, dplyr, vctrs

Would you know a way to construct an empty **grouped** `data.frame` or `tibble` in `dplyr`?

This is the best that I could come up with for a constructor of a custom `grouped_df` class, but I don't like it as the result in fact isn't a true `grouped_df`.

```
library(dplyr)
new_df_custom_grouped <- function(x = group_by(tibble())) {
  # stopifnot(is_grouped_df(x))
  structure(x, 
    class = c("tbl_df_custom_grouped", "tbl_df_custom", class(x)))
}
```

### Motivation

In the pursuit of making my code compliant with [tidy code principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/manifesto.html), I looked into the [section about constructors for S3 classes](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-classes) of the Advanced R book.

To define a custom method for `dplyr::group_by()` while using *cast* methods as layed out in the [article on S3 vectors](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/articles/s3-vector.html) of the `vctrs` package, I need a constructor for a custom grouped data frame (see `vctrs` [GitHub issue #155](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/155) if you're interested in the details).